# Average on overlapping windows in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools, moving-average

I'm trying to compute a moving average but with a set step size between each average. For example, if I was computing the average of a 4 element window every 2 elements:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

This should produce the average of [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10].

```
window_avg = [2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 8.5]
```

My data is such that the ending will be truncated before processing so there is no problem with the length with respect to window size.

I've read a bit about how to do moving averages in Python and there seems to be a lot of usage of itertools; however, the iterators go one element at a time and I can't figure out how to have a step size between each calculation of the average. 
([How to calculate moving average in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884017/how-to-calculate-moving-average-in-python-3-3))

I have also been able to do this before in MATLAB by creating a matrix of indices which are overlapping and then indexing the data vector and performing a column wise mean ([Create matrix by repeatedly overlapping a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966512/create-matrix-by-repeatedly-overlapping-a-vector)). However, since this vector is rather large (~70 000 elements, window of 450 samples, average every 30 samples), the computation would probably require too much memory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: I would try something along the lines of `n=4; s==2; [sum(data[s*i:s*i+n])/n for i, datum in enumerate(data[::s])]`, but perhaps that's not what you looking for (`datum` here is unnecessary, but `range(len(data))` just looks so unPythonic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to compute the average of a sliding window across a list in Python is to use a list comprehension. You can use

```
>>> range(0, len(data), 2)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

to get the starting indices of each window, and then `numpy`'s `mean` function to take the average of each window. See the demo below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> window_size = 4
>>> stride = 2
>>> window_avg = [ np.mean(data[i:i+window_size]) for i in range(0, len(data), stride)
                   if i+window_size <= len(data) ]
>>> window_avg
[2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 8.5]
```

Note that the list comprehension does have a condition to ensure that it only computes the average of "full windows", or sublists with exactly `window_size` elements.

When run on a dataset of the size discussed in the OP, this method computes on my MBA in a little over 200 ms:

```
In [5]: window_size = 450
In [6]: data = range(70000)
In [7]: stride = 30
In [8]: timeit [ np.mean(data[i:i+window_size]) for i in range(0, len(data), stride)
                 if i+window_size <= len(data) ]
1 loops, best of 3: 220 ms per loop
```

It is about twice as fast on my machine to the `itertools` approach presented by @Abhijit:

```
In [9]: timeit map(np.mean, izip(*(islice(it, i, None, stride) for i, it in enumerate(tee(data, window_size)))))
1 loops, best of 3: 436 ms per loop
```

Comment: what's the efficiency for mass data?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I added a speed benchmark for the dataset mentioned in the OP.

Comment: seems Abhijit's solution is much faster: *6.19 ms per loop*

Comment: @zhangxaochen: interesting, I tried benchmarking his approach, too, and found the opposite. Can you verify what you got looking at my updated answer?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I believe, there might be something wrong with your bench-marking, mdml's approach is considerably faster, per my benchmarking

Answer (score 1):

The following approach uses itertools at its fullest to create moving average window of size `4`. As then entire expression is a generator which is evaluated when calculating the average, it has a complexity of O(n).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from itertools import count, tee, izip, islice
>>> map(np.mean, izip(*(islice(it,i,None,2)
                      for i, it in enumerate(tee(data, 4)))))
[2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 8.5]
```

Its interesting to note, how individual itertools function works in accord.

1. `itertools.tee` n-plicates an iterator, in this case 4 times
2. enumerate creates an enumerator object which yield a tuple of index and element (which is the iterator)
3. slice the iterator with stride 2, starting from the index position.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is more along the lines of what I expected with an itertools implementation and is very informative. I'm surprised that this is actually slower than the other answer since my understanding was that itertools is faster than using a list comprehension in many cases. That being said, I am selecting mdml's answer since it's faster and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rolling function of Pandas DataFrame,

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> 
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
9  10
```

Using Pandas DataFrame's rolling function,

```
df.rolling(4).mean().dropna()[::2]
>>> 
     0
3  2.5
5  4.5
7  6.5
9  8.5
```

4 is the window size and 2 in [::2] can be assumed to be step size.
Actually, `df.rolling(4).mean().dropna()` shift the window 1-by-1 and by applying index [::2], we pick one after taking two steps.

Alternatively,
If you have Pandas version > 1.5, you can give step size. Note that, center argument must be 'True'. The solution:

```
df.rolling(4, step=2, center=True).mean().dropna()

>>> df
     0
2  2.5
4  4.5
6  6.5
8  8.5
```